# Erro Post - Payload (Node.js)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, post, mongoose, express.js

Hoje quando fui realizar o post de uma base 64 maior está retornando isso do meu servidor. Quando é feito o upload de uma imagem menor ele envia sem problemas, eu tentei utilizar algumas soluções limitando o server para 50mb mas não funcionou.

```
server.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}))
server.use(bodyParse.json({type:'json/*', limit: '50mb'}))
```

Está retornando estes erros na requisição:

[image: Erro do servidor]

Este é a parte do front a requisição que da erro:

[image: Erro Front-end]